# Issue with the requested skill's response on Alexa LaunchRequest

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm trying to invoke a skill and am getting "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" message back from Alexa.

Here's the Alexa request:

```
{

   "version": "1.0",

   "session": {

     "new": true,

     "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.84e6d5c5-6254-43dd-bb28-f3b434b71857",

     "application": {

       "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.db1bac88-183d-409c-9d3e-0e69fa0f5fe2"

     },

     "user": {

       "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGX2NO3NXXDS6NLEZMDZXMRZZPJ3DLEERYK7J3NUPFUYRADFB2HRILB7BZVTN336OFVSNFFUP3VDVFHERK5PKQE5H32EQ5GGWTT67EMDQKP22Q7NTXXNYDUTYNCYI6EJUEODQ54VHKW4JSWVCS7JINWLYH2LICQVETFGZBY6NBDJVEX66VCGCZMRTFZYAG2E3IXDPMPVF3U4VMY"

     }

   },

   "context": {

     "System": {

       "application": {

         "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.db1bac88-183d-409c-9d3e-0e69fa0f5fe2"

       },

       "user": {

         "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGX2NO3NXXDS6NLEZMDZXMRZZPJ3DLEERYK7J3NUPFUYRADFB2HRILB7BZVTN336OFVSNFFUP3VDVFHERK5PKQE5H32EQ5GGWTT67EMDQKP22Q7NTXXNYDUTYNCYI6EJUEODQ54VHKW4JSWVCS7JINWLYH2LICQVETFGZBY6NBDJVEX66VCGCZMRTFZYAG2E3IXDPMPVF3U4VMY"

       },

       "device": {

         "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AGUTTO7VCXPCUUSXNDCNO6LK7LZHUKPDGZBOXUOBNRNOBGD7FHBJWHOK3LJNQX4U47HTFLUXJ6MHBL6V7UCDNTWOMBJIP5R4R2ZVK3XJX42PEZG6J6TCS3U7NSYZZ3PDCUSH22CY7LYGNIK2MGXCUGR4ITQQ",

         "supportedInterfaces": {}

       },

       "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",

       "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.UfUNTw8ZOZQmiIldke2vocscZ6EuLHFj42E2NWIYP1gUOT_lwwlDWHrnteFOASzeZ2RGNWWVAcL173oFdJAYMFHgYZO9qcDyDxzyB8UsKNc47mrCFNhcd1_jtUWWNIoWk1DK8FpuaIDgsE_kRqWqNcpgsZ4OzVolOJsNnbOTTId1AYz1F1f6FXvLBqLywbEuTNI60kaLVEopa9pnbqyQt57UC1JrN0J6ShvvQCH9FBvD0uYCvmcuuQrv5f3JYSVxSqdXuvjVmmzL3xEtpmJyxwu-EnTvXregzD3o2UVEIaIJnCFFf9jv30hupClk1MlAJZQiBYsJBkqCLsxTdrrSzQ"

     }

   },

   "request": {

     "type": "LaunchRequest",

     "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.0c7adbd0-136b-4511-b5cc-2c57e4e8ff60",

     "timestamp": "2018-08-23T14:24:41Z",

     "locale": "en-US",

     "shouldLinkResultBeReturned": false

   }

}
```

​

Interaction Schema:

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "speech p o c",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": [
                        "good bye",
                        "i'm done",
                        "thank you i'm done"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "RawText",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "Text",
                            "type": "ABC_Text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{Text}",
                        "ask abc to {Text}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.RepeatIntent",
                    "samples": []
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "ABC_Text",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "how much do i owe"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "how much did i spend on coffee last week"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "hello"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "where is the nearest atm"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the endpoint information:

[image]

Hitting the same endpoint webhook locally works fine and produces the expected response:

[image]
What could I be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot retuen a plain text as response. Alexa expect a valid response json.

Comment: Where can I find a schema for the responses that Alexa is expecting which I can produce?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a plain text as Alexa's response.

Use the json structure mentioned [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html)